# Canot install Xubuntu on LG R450 M.AD25E

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu

[image]After initial screen with a keyboard (?) icon in the bottom screen goes black and stays this way untill I reboot.
Tried booting from DVD disk and USB stick created with Etcher.

The laptop has the following hardware:

```
Pentium Dual-Core T4300 CPU
3GB DDR2 RAM
SIS 6531 Mirage 3 graphics adapter
```

[Edit] Added log screenshot with latest messages

[Edit 2] I found an old thread about the same issue. I will check their sugestions and report back. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2319539

Comment: before you login your system, go to TTY session (press Ctrl-Alt-F1), login there, see if doesn't lock. So, type `sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog`. return to GUI, do a login, revert o TTY1 and watch any output till freeze or anyelse.

Comment: @Redbob I never get to the login. I am trying to start Xubuntu from the installation disc ("Try Xubuntu without installing" option). I can get to the boot options there, but not much else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `noapic nolapic` to boot options solved the problem.